# How to use fake Dummy-SMTP with codeigniters email library

Tags: php, python-2.7, email, codeigniter-3

There are snippets of answers for different problems that solve the issues here, but you need to put them all together.

The problem here is trying to setup some sort of dummy/fake smtp service on your linux computer for testing the email functionality of a codeigniter based system.

So I found a fake smtp python script here:

http://www.technoreply.com/finally-a-dummy-smtp-for-linux/

So far so good.

You follow the instructions to start the dummy SMTP service and it runs fine. You can test it with telnet port 25 in another terminal.

So then you implement the codeigniter email library and do something like this:

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'localhost';
$config['smtp_port'] = 25;
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('xxxx@xxxxx.com', 'XXXX');
$this->email->to('yyyy@yyyyy.com);

$this->email->subject('Test Subject');
$this->email->message('body ....');
$this->email->send( false );
```

And then the trouble begins:

> 220 puggle Python SMTP proxy version 0.2
>   hello: The following SMTP error was encountered: 
>   Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to >send mail using this method.

The process also hangs, and particularly at the point where the system is trying to read from the socket connecting to the dummy SMTP service.

At about line 2304 in system/libraries/Email.php

```
while ($str = fgets($this->_smtp_connect, 512))
```

That we will denote as problem 1!

When this problem is resolved (yes I will answer that later - please be patient!) you will not doubt find another problem to deal with.

The email process fails with the following:

> 220 puggle Python SMTP proxy version 0.2
>   hello: 502 Error: command "EHLO" not implemented
>   The following SMTP error was encountered: 502 Error: command "EHLO" not implemented

So unfortunately, the Dummy SMTP service does not support EHLO!

Comment: Can you try using mailsnag.com and see if you are having errors. If it is your code’s (and not server) fault, then it will show up there too. Also it shows you smtp log which is nice for debugging

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is similar to this issue:

[Can't send email from gmail in codeigniter, SMTP Authentication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19926810/cant-send-email-from-gmail-in-codeigniter-smtp-authentication-error)

The default setting in the codeigniter Email.php library is to use newlines as:

At about line 180 in system/libraries/Email.php

```
public $newline     = "\n";
```

You can change this here to:

```
public $newline     = "\r\n";
```

And the email process will stop hanging.
However, if you do not want to update the core components (which makes sense if you are going to be updating these regularly), then you can follow the suggestion in the related question and add this to your code:

```
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
```

The solution to problem 2 involves some dirty work with python's library:

So someone had this problem here:

[Receiving email with SMTPServer in python:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868262/receiving-email-with-smtpserver-in-python)

which I have suggested can be fixed by replicating the HELO function into a EHLO function:

You will probably find the smtpd.py file in /usr/lib/python2.7

```
def smtp_HELO(self, arg):
    if not arg:
        self.push('501 Syntax: HELO hostname')
        return
    if self.__greeting:
        self.push('503 Duplicate HELO/EHLO')
    else:
        self.__greeting = arg
        self.push('250 %s' % self.__fqdn)

#copy the above function and rename it smtp_EHLO

def smtp_EHLO(self, arg):
    if not arg:
        self.push('501 Syntax: HELO hostname')
        return
    if self.__greeting:
        self.push('503 Duplicate HELO/EHLO')
    else:
        self.__greeting = arg
        self.push('250 %s' % self.__fqdn)
```

And as surely as PHP6 follows PHP5 (?) the problem is now fixed.

Now, someone will point out that I have once again applied a patch to a core library, this time a python one (and I am not a python developer!). No doubt, sometime down the track I will update my python libraries and lose this fix.

So if a python developer can tell me how to apply this extension to the smtpd class from outside the core code, that would be the icing on the top of the cake!